# Setting a minimum height of a container on page load prototype

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs, pageload

Ok, so I am trying to set the minimum height of a container dynamically on page load using prototype so that the page displays correctly. My header and footer equal 345px in height, so I am trying to set my main-container div's minimum height to be the window's inner height minus these dimensions when the page loads, so even pages with no content in these fivs will appear correctly. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var minHeight = window.innerHeight;
    minHeight -= 345;
    $('main-container').style.minHeight = minHeight;
});
```

and:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var minHeight = window.innerHeight;
    minHeight -= 345;
    $('main-container').setStyle({
        minHeight : minHeight
    });
});
```

I know the script fires on page load via an alert in the document.observe function, but it isn't adding the height or throwing any errors. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Andrew for answering, I have also added this code for when the user resizes and thought I'd share:

```
Event.observe(window, 'resize', function() {
    var minHeight = window.innerHeight;
    minHeight -= 345;
    $('main-container').setStyle({
        'min-height' : minHeight+'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldnt `minHeight : minHeight` be `'min-height' : minHeight+'px'`

Comment: @Andrew that was the solution, thanks :)

Comment: I have put it in as an answer so that it is easier to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldnt `minHeight : minHeight` be `'min-height' : minHeight+'px'`